how to prove identity for nth derivative of $(\text{arctanh}(x))^j$?
I worked on integral problem and I got that
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\ln \left(\frac{1-x}{1+x} \right) } dx=-\frac{2}{(n+1)!}\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}F(n,j) \eta'(-j)$$
where $\eta(x)$ is Dirichlet eta function and
$$ F(n,j)=\sum_{p=1}^{n} \binom{n-1}{p-1} \sum_{m=j}^{n+1} \binom{m}{j} |s(n+1,m)| ((-p)^{m-j}+(1-p)^{m-j})$$
where $s(n,m)$ is Stirling numbers of first kind
and I searched for simple identity for $F(n,j)$ and I got this five identities
$$ F(n,j)=0  , n\equiv j   \mod2$$
$$ F(n,n+1)=2^n$$
$$ F(n,n-1)=2^{n-1} \binom{n+1}{3}$$
$$ F(2n,1)=(2n)!$$
$$ F(2n+1,2)=2(2n+1)!\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2k+1}$$
and finally I found that
$$ F(n,j)=\frac{2^{j-1}}{j!} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}} (\text{arctanh}(x))^j$$
which means that
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}} (\text{arctanh}(x))^j=j! 2^{1-j}\sum_{p=1}^{n} \binom{n-1}{p-1} \sum_{m=j}^{n+1} \binom{m}{j} |s(n+1,m)| ((-p)^{m-j}+(1-p)^{m-j})$$
then I got explicit formula for A049214 , A049215 and A049216
now my questions
How to prove the last formula ?
is there simple formula for that double summation ?
How to prove five identities for $F(n,j)$ that I put ?

You can notice $\tanh^{-1}(x)^j=2^{-j}\ln(1+\frac2{x-1})^j$, apply the generating function for the Stirling numbers of the first kind, and differentiate. Probably after some manipulations, you will get the finite sums.

@TymaGaidash --- I have worked this out at https://mathoverflow.net/a/477203/11260
